# Cucumber feature for twitter bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, testing, cucumber, twitter-bootstrap

I'm writing a cucumber feature were I want to delete a category, but before I delete it I show a modal screen to ask the user for his conformation.

I'm using twitter bootstrap and use the javscript modals they provide.

But I'm stuck, so could anybody help in the right direct on how I could test this.
This is my feature so far:

```
  Scenario: Delete category with articles
   Given I am logged in as an admin
   And I have category titled Paints
   When I go to the list of categories
   And I push delete button for the Paints category
   Then I should get a popup to confirm
```

I already implemented the necessary steps for the feature accepts the last one of course.
But I don't have a clue how to start:

I read something about page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert but don't now if that can work.

Does anybody have some advice ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I tried this approach:  page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept but then I get No alert is present (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoAlertPresentError)

Comment: I believe the tb modal is just a div, so maybe verify the text in the confirmation modal, it is not a 'normal' js confirm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you suggested in your question, you can access the dialog box with the [Selenium Driver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RubyBindings).  I am assuming you are using Capybara, so here is how you could define your step definitions for accepting/canceling the popups:

```
Then /^I accept the popup to confirm$/
  page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept 
end

Then /^I cancel the popup to confirm$/
 page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.dismiss
end
```

**EDIT**: It seems the modal is actually not a window...Let's try it like this:

Create a helper function to detect that the modal element is around:

```
def find_modal_element
  wait_until { page.find(modal_element_id).visible? }
end
```

Then let's change the step definition:

```
Then /^I should see a popup window$/
 find_modal_element
 page.find(modal_element_id).text.must_match "Whatever you want it to match"
end
```

Comment: Still experiencing some problems, the way of testing it like this makes my tests very unstable. Sometimes I get this error: Element cannot be scrolled into view: ... (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::MoveTargetOutOfBoundsError). Any idea how I could make the test more robust?

Comment: also, wait_until is being deprecated in favor of `page.find(..., visible: true)`

Comment: In place of `page.find(modal_element_id).text.must_match "Whatever you want it to match"` I used `expect(page.find(modal_element_id).text).to eql("Whatever you want it to match")`.  But thanks for the hint!

Comment: Also, you need `@javascript` before your `Scenario` or Cucumber will be fooled into thinking the modal is open all the time.